# How to optimize multiple subqueries that are running for lookup tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two looK up tables, and need is to fetch value by correlating the both tables.

As of now I am doing this with multiple sub queries and trying to find a easiest way.

```
 SELECT
  (SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM T1 where FK_T2 = (SELECT  PK FROM  T2 WHERE  T2.ID = 'A') AND T1.ID = 'AA')as A,
  (SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM T1 where FK_T2 = (SELECT  PK FROM  T2 WHERE  T2.ID = 'B') AND T1.ID = 'BB')AS B,
  (SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM T1 where FK_T2 = (SELECT  PK FROM  T2 WHERE  T2.ID = 'C') AND T1.ID = 'CC')AS C,
  (SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM T1 where FK_T2 = (SELECT  PK FROM  T2 WHERE  T2.ID = 'D') AND T1.ID = 'DD')AS D,
  (SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM T1 where FK_T2 = (SELECT  PK FROM  T2 WHERE  T2.ID = 'E') AND T1.ID = 'EE')AS E,
  (SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM T1 where FK_T2 = (SELECT  PK FROM  T2 WHERE  T2.ID = 'F') AND T1.ID = 'FF')AS F
   FROM MYTABLE;
```

Comment: What is your expected output here?

Comment: OUTPUT would be that am getting from above query but finding a way to remove these multiple query as there is more then 10 times  running same query.  These above queries I have used in my stored procedure.

Comment: @Tim I have updated the query for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you need something like this.

```
   SELECT  MAX ( CASE WHEN T1.ID = 'AA' AND T2.ID = 'A' THEN TYPE_NAME  END ) as A,
           MAX ( CASE WHEN T1.ID = 'BB' AND T2.ID = 'B' THEN TYPE_NAME  END ) as B,
           MAX ( CASE WHEN T1.ID = 'CC' AND T2.ID = 'C' THEN TYPE_NAME  END ) as C,
           ..

    FROM T1 t1
    INNER JOIN T2 t2
        ON t1.FK_T2 = t2.PK
```

Comment: It will work for me just need to put When as you missed in above query. @Kaushik can you please also give me suggestion that which one have better performance multiple subquries as I am using or the other one you mentioned. Please justifie so that I can push it to production.

Comment: @D.J. : Thanks for the edit. It is difficult to say which query would give a better performance without knowing the volume, structure and design of your tables. But, in a first glance, it appears to be clear that the number of sub-queries have been reduced, thus reducing the repetitive look-ups from the table for each value of t1.id. I would suggest you to run the explain plan for both the queries, check if there is any improvement in the performance and proceed further.Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try something like:

```
SELECT
    T1.TYPE_NAME,
    T1.ID
FROM T1 t1
INNER JOIN T2 t2
    ON t1.FK_T2 = t2.PK
WHERE
    T1.ID||T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: You have the logic of your `WHERE` clause switched I believe, i.e. it should be `WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID || T2.ID` ... but this assumes that the values shown in the OP are actual, and not just placeholders as an example.

Comment: I wrote the where assuming that the values in the question are the real ones

Comment: No these are just dummy values. We can't do it by appending one ID to Another both are different.

Comment: @D.J. I don't know what those 2 table represents in your domain but i'll say that the project of that 2 lookup it's just a mess

Answer (score 1):

You could try rephrasing these queries as a single query consisting of a join between the two tables:

```
SELECT
    T1.TYPE_NAME,
    T1.ID
FROM T1 t1
INNER JOIN T2 t2
    ON t1.FK_T2 = t2.PK
WHERE
    (T1.ID = 'AA' AND T2.ID = 'A') OR
    (T1.ID = 'BB' AND T2.ID = 'B') OR
    (T1.ID = 'CC' AND T2.ID = 'C') OR
    (T1.ID = 'DD' AND T2.ID = 'D') OR
    (T1.ID = 'EE' AND T2.ID = 'E') OR
    (T1.ID = 'FF' AND T2.ID = 'F');
```

You can keep track of to which subquery each returned record corresponds by checking the value of the `ID` column in the first table.  This would serve as a marker for the source subquery.